# Difference of Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $B = \{1,2,3\}$, $C = \{2,5\}$

If $x\notin B$ then it is true to say that $x\notin B-C$ as well

But is it true the other way around? That is to say,
If $x\notin B-C$, then $x\notin B$.

If $x= 2$, $B-C= \{1,3\}$, hence it is true that $x$ is not an element of $B-C$.

BUT, $x$ is an element of $B$. So i conclude that it is not true the other way around.

But one of the solutions to my test was this. Notice the parts highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\notin B-C$, then $x\in C\cup B^c$. Therefore, if $C\cap B\neq\emptyset$, you can have $x\in B$.

In your correction, if $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$ and $x\notin B-C$, in particular, $x\in A$, $x\notin C$ and $x\in C\cup B^c$. But since $x\notin C$, even if $C\cap B\neq\emptyset$, since $x\notin C$, you can't have $x\in B$. Then, $x\notin B$ is correct.

Comment: omg thanks! nice nice

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the converse is not true as you show in your example. In the test, however, the situation is different, there we have $x\notin C$ by the first line in the converse way.